# C++ sprintf from unknown argument

Tags: c++, node.js, printf

Try to write a nodejs sprintf native implementation while improving my c++ skills, i've reseach on how to provide unknown lenghth of arguments to sprintf. I first though i could use vsprintf but couldn't find how to populate it. basically, the nodejs/v8 binding give me an argument array which i could convert to a vector or sommething else, but don't know how to convert it to va_list expected by vsprintf or any other alternative that could make it work.

Does any one could propose me a strategy?

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's compiler and platform dependant. You can look at the implementation of `va_start` and `va_arg` etc for your compiler of choice, and push the data in the correct manner into the stack using the `asm` directive.

I wouldn't do that though, if it's critical for your implementation to imitate `sprintf` - loop on the parameters and process them one at a time concatenating results, that would be much more robust and portable.

Comment: Assembler not required... you can arrange the data in any old byte array and create a `va_list` that points to it, since `va_list` really is nothing but a pointer.  It still would be very implementation-specific though, and since he'd have to process the format string anyway to find out the data types to store, he might as well process it piecemeal as you recommend.